# How can I write to a YUV allocation in Renderscript?

Tags: android, performance, renderscript

I'm trying to do some image pre-processing on an Android device using Renderscript. After obtaining a YUV_420_888 allocation from the Camera2 API, I pass it through a series of scripts. Although Renderscript provides `rsGetElementAtYuv_uchar_*` to access each component from a YUV allocation, I cant find any documentation or source code that allows writing to a separate YUV allocation. It seems like every example converts to RGBA and then continues using those allocations.

If I had 3 separate allocations for each component, it would be fairly simple to use `rsSetElementAt` using `x >> 1` and `y >> 1` for the u and v components, but I'd like to represent it as a single allocation (which can be passed to the next script).

Is there a way to access the chroma components using the allocation? (i.e. is there some pointer to the uv planes?)

This is my first post on SO, so please let me know what I could improve!

Comment: Doesn't the wikipedia article on YUV: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV answer your question?

Comment: There are a lot of references for how to convert YUV -> RGBA, or how to access UV planes for different YUV formats, but nothing for renderscript specifically. What I'm looking for is how to pass an `rs_allocation` to my script, access values using `rsGetElementAtYuv_uchar_*` and then write modified values back.